# How to detect advertisement link?

Tags: html, algorithm, data-analysis

I want to detect the links in page which are used for advertisement. Or is there any statistical data by which I can guess this link is for advertisement?

Comment: You may want to find out how AdBlock works, see: http://adblockplus.org/en/faq_internal and http://askville.amazon.com/Adblock-Firefox-work/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=14164730 and http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_does_AdBlock_work?_Do_I_have_to_configure_it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a concrete answer, but if I were doing the same, I'd take a look at AdBlock and other add-ons in browsers such as Firefox since they do much the same. There are quite a few open source add-ons out there where you can view the code that does this. And even most email programs detect junk mail (and ads) using Bayesian filters which I'm sure with a bit of tweaking would work well.

Comment: This is not actually helped me very much. Could you please tell me, is there some common or related properties of advertisement link?